# Need some light on @oneToMany using Map and @MapKeyColumn

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

This is my sql table structure,

```
create table TBL_DEPARTMENT_ONE(
   ID integer primary key generated always as  identity  (start with 50, increment by 1),
   name varchar(100)
)

create table TBL_EMPLOYEE_THREE(
   ID integer primary key generated always as  identity  (start with 100, increment by 1),
   name varchar(100),
   dept_ID integer references  TBL_DEPARTMENT_ONE
)
```

Here we i'v done a structure of one to many relation between Employee and Department where many employees can belong to one Department,

Now, here is the JPA mapping code as follows,
For Employee,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEE_THREE")
public class EmployeeEntityThree implements Serializable{
    public EmployeeEntityThree(){}

    public EmployeeEntityThree(String name,String mobileNo,DepartmentEntityOne dept){
       this.empName = name;
       this.department = dept;
       this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Column(name="MOBILE_NO")
    private String mobileNo;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,
                        CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch= FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=DepartmentEntityOne.class) 
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID")
    private DepartmentEntityOne department;
    .....
    ...
}
```

the code below is of Department Entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_DEPARTMENT_ONE")
public class DepartmentEntityOne implements Serializable{
    public DepartmentEntityOne(){ }

    public DepartmentEntityOne(String name){
             this.deptName = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer deptId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String deptName;

    @OneToMany(cascade= {   CascadeType.MERGE, 
                                  CascadeType.PERSIST},
                   fetch= FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="department")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="xxxxx")
    private Map<String,EmployeeEntityThree> employees;
    ...
    ..
}
```

This is the code in my main method for testing,

```
DepartmentEntityOne deptOne = new DepartmentEntityOne("Mechanical Engineering");
Map<String,EmployeeEntityThree> empMap = new HashMap<String,EmployeeEntityThree>();
EmployeeEntityThree[] array = new EmployeeEntityThree[]{
     new EmployeeEntityThree("Amar","9000000001",deptOne),
     new EmployeeEntityThree("Akbar","9000000002",deptOne),
     new EmployeeEntityThree("Anthony","9000000003",deptOne)
};
empMap.put(array[0].getMobileNo(),array[0]);
empMap.put(array[1].getMobileNo(),array[1]);
empMap.put(array[2].getMobileNo(),array[2]);
deptOne.setEmployees(empMap);
em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.persist(deptOne);
```

The code works fine with all the inserts done successfully

Now my Question is for the Entity Department
where is have used an @MapKeyColumn(name="xxxx"), where "xxxx" is some garbage value,
Here what should be the name = ?
because prior to this it was name = "mobileNo" which is the property in Employee entity.
This worked too.

So what shoud be the actualy vaue for @MapKetColumn(name= ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the `name` column of the `Employee` table.

```
@MapKeyColumn(name="NAME")
private Map<String,EmployeeEntityThree> employees;
```

Comment: but if i put id as the name value, it refers to auto generated Id of employee entity, so while testing i am only able to insert only one emplyee even i put 3 employee info in HashMap(),

Comment: @Rahul Shivsharan, whoops that makes sense, then switch to the name column, it needs to be a column on Employee.

Comment: means, any column in Employee table which hold a unique hashcode in its java mapping, right ?